# R Aggregate over multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

i´m currently working with a large dataframe of 75 columns and round about 9500 rows. This dataframe contains observations for every day from 1995-2019 for several observation points.

Edit: The print from dput(head(df))

```
> dput(head(df))
structure(list(date = structure(c(9131, 9132, 9133, 9134, 9135, 
9136), class = "Date"), x1 = c(50.75, 62.625, 57.25, 56.571, 
36.75, 39.125), x2 = c(62.25, 58.714, 49.875, 56.375, 43.25, 
41.625), x3 = c(90.25, NA, 70.125, 75.75, 83.286, 98.5), 
    x4 = c(60, 72, 68.375, 65.5, 63.25, 55.875), x5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), xn = c(53.25, 
    61.143, 56.571, 58.571, 36.25, 44.375), year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
    1995, 1995), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), day = c(1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

The dataframe looks like this sample from it:

```
date             x1      x2     x3       x4       x5     xn     year    month    day
  <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1995-01-01    50.8    62.2    90.2    60        NA    53.2    1995      1    1
2 1999-08-02    62.6    58.7    NA      72        NA    61.1    1999      8    2
3 2001-09-03    57.2    49.9    70.1    68.4      NA    56.6    2001      9    3
4 2008-05-04    56.6    56.4    75.8    65.5      NA    58.6    2008      5    4
5 2012-04-05    36.8    43.2    83.3    63.2      NA    36.2    2012      4    5
6 2019-12-31    39.1    41.6    98.5    55.9      NA    44.4    2019      12   31
```

```
str(df)
tibble [9,131 x 75] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ date   : Date[1:9131], format: "1995-01-01" "1995-01-02" ...
 $ x1     : num [1:9131] 50.8 62.6 57.2 56.6 36.8 ...
 $ x2     : num [1:9131] 62.2 58.7 49.9 56.4 43.2 ...
   xn
 $ year   : num [1:9131] 1995 1995 1995 1995 1995 ...
 $ month  : num [1:9131] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ day    : num [1:9131] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

**My goal is to get for every observation point xn the count of all observations which cross a certain limit per year.
So far i tried to reach this with the Aggregate function.**

To get the mean of every year i used the following command:

```
aggregate(list(df), by=list(year=df$year), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

this works perfect, i get the mean for every year for every observation point.

To get the sum of one station i used the following code

```
aggregate(list(x1=df$x1), by=list(year=df$year), function(x) sum(rle(x)$values>120, na.rm=TRUE))
```

which results in this print:

```
   year      x1
1  1995      52
2  1996      43
3  1997      44
4  1998      42
5  1999      38
6  2000      76
7  2001      52
8  2002      58
9  2003     110
10 2004      34
11 2005      64
12 2006      46
13 2007      46
14 2008      17
15 2009      41
16 2010      30
17 2011      40
18 2012      47
19 2013      40
20 2014      21
21 2015      56
22 2016      27
23 2017      45
24 2018      22
25 2019      45
```

So far, so good. I know i could expand the code by adding (..,x2=data$x2, x3=data$x3,..xn) to the list argument in code above. which i tried and they work.

But how do I get them all at once?

I tried the following codes:

```
aggregate(.~(date, year, month, day), by=list(year=df$year), function(x) sum(rle(x)$values>120, na.rm=TRUE))
Fehler: Unerwartete(s) ',' in "aggregate(.~(date,"
```

```
aggregate(.~date+year+month+day, by=list(year=df$year), function(x) sum(rle(x)$values>120, na.rm=TRUE))
Fehler in as.data.frame.default(data, optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

```
aggregate(. ~ date + year + month + day, data = df,by=list(year=df$year), function(x) sum(rle(x)$values>120, na.rm=TRUE))
Fehler in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  Argumente müssen dieselbe Länge haben
```

But unfortunately none of them works. Could someone please give me a hint where my mistake is?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)).  These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Hello Andre. Are you asking how to sum the columns in the input data frame, but only for those years where there are at least 120 observations in the year, or are you asking to sum all columns by year for each column that has at least 120 non-missing observations in a year, or something else?

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the advice. I added the dput(head(df)).

Comment: @LenGreski

Hej Len, no I actually wanna know how many observations in a year are greater than 120. And this for every station xn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer that uses base R, and since none of the data in the example data is above 120, we set a criterion of above 70.

```
data <- structure(
     list(
          date = structure(c(9131, 9132, 9133, 9134, 9135,
                             9136), class = "Date"),
          x1 = c(50.75, 62.625, 57.25, 56.571,
                 36.75, 39.125),
          x2 = c(62.25, 58.714, 49.875, 56.375, 43.25,
                 41.625),
          x3 = c(90.25, NA, 70.125, 75.75, 83.286, 98.5),
          x4 = c(60, 72, 68.375, 65.5, 63.25, 55.875),
          x5 = c(NA_real_,
                 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_),
          xn = c(53.25,
                 61.143, 56.571, 58.571, 36.25, 44.375),
          year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995,
                   1995, 1995),
          month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
          day = c(1, 2, 3,
                  4, 5, 6)
     ),
     row.names = c(NA,-6L),
     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl",
               "data.frame"
     ))
```

First, we create a subset of the data that contains all columns containing `x`, and set them to TRUE or FALSE based on whether the value is greater than 70.

```
theCols <- data[,colnames(data)[grepl("x",colnames(data))]]
```

Second, we `cbind()` the year onto the matrix of logical values.

```
x_logical <- cbind(year = data$year,as.data.frame(apply(theCols,2,function(x) x > 70)))
```

Finally, we use aggregate across all columns other than `year` and sum the columns.

```
aggregate(x_logical[2:ncol(x_logical)],by = list(x_logical$year),sum,na.rm=TRUE)
```

...and the output:

```
  Group.1 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 xn
1    1995  0  0  5  1  0  0
>
```

Note that by using `colnames()` to extract the columns that start with `x` and `nrow()` in the `aggregate()` function, we make this a general solution that will handle a varying number of `x` locations.

### Two tidyverse solutions

A tidyverse solution to the same problem is as follows. It includes the following steps.

1. Use `mutate()` with `across()` to create the TRUE / FALSE versions of the `x` variables. Note that `across()` requires dplyr 1.0.0, which is currently in development but due for production release the week of May 25th.
2. Use `pivot_longer()` to allow us to `summarise()` multiple measures without a lot of complicated code.
3. Use `pivot_wider()` to convert the data back to one column for each `x` measurement.

...and the code is:

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr") # needed for across()
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 
library(lubridate) 
data %>%
     mutate(.,across(starts_with("x"),~if_else(. > 70,TRUE,FALSE))) %>%
        select(-year,-month,-day) %>% group_by(date) %>% 
        pivot_longer(starts_with("x"),names_to = "measure",values_to = "value") %>% 
        mutate(year = year(date)) %>% group_by(year,measure) %>%
        select(-date) %>% 
                summarise(value = sum(value,na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
        pivot_wider(id_cols = year,names_from = "measure",
                    values_from = value)
```

...and the output, which matches the Base R solution that I originally posted:

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'year' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 1 x 7
# Groups:   year [1]
   year    x1    x2    x3    x4    x5    xn
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  1995     0     0     5     1     0     0
>
```

...and here's an edited version of the other answer that will also produce the same results as above. This solution implements `pivot_longer()` before creating the logical variable for exceeding the threshold, so it does not require the `across()` function. Also note that since this uses 120 as the threshold value and none of the data meets this threshold, the sums are all 0.

```
df_example %>% 
        pivot_longer(x1:x5) %>% 
        mutate(greater_120 = value > 120) %>% 
        group_by(year,name) %>% 
        summarise(sum_120 = sum(greater_120,na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
        pivot_wider(id_cols = year,names_from = "name", values_from = sum_120)
```

...and the output:

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'year' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 1 x 6
# Groups:   year [1]
   year    x1    x2    x3    x4    x5
  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1  1995     0     0     0     0     0
>
```

### Conclusions

As usual, there are many ways to accomplish a given task in R. Depending on one's preferences, the problem can be solved with Base R or the tidyverse. One of the quirks of the tidyverse is that some operations such as `summarise()` are much easier to perform on narrow format tidy data than on wide format data. Therefore, it's important to be proficient with `tidyr::pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()` when working in the tidyverse.

That said, with the production release of dplyr 1.0.0, the team at RStudio continues to add features that facilitate working with wide format data.

Comment: @LenGrenski, your solution worked really well. I adapted into my aggregate code, which now looks like this:

```
aggregate(df[,colnames(df)[grepl("x",colnames(df))]], by=list(year=df$year), function(x) sum(rle(x)$values>70, na.rm=TRUE))

```

It produces the same result like your solution, so thats perfect. Thanks a lot and have a nice weekend!

Comment: @André_1090 - Thanks for the feedback, Andre. I just posted a tidyverse solution to the problem in case you're interested in that approach.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
df_example <- structure(list(date = structure(c(9131, 9132, 9133, 9134, 9135, 
                                                9136), class = "Date"), x1 = c(50.75, 62.625, 57.25, 56.571, 
                                                                               36.75, 39.125), x2 = c(62.25, 58.714, 49.875, 56.375, 43.25, 
                                                                                                      41.625), x3 = c(90.25, NA, 70.125, 75.75, 83.286, 98.5), 
                             x4 = c(60, 72, 68.375, 65.5, 63.25, 55.875), x5 = c(NA_real_, 
                                                                                 NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), xn = c(53.25, 
                                                                                                                                           61.143, 56.571, 58.571, 36.25, 44.375), year = c(1995, 1995, 1995, 1995, 
                                                                                                                                                                                            1995, 1995), month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), day = c(1, 2, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "data.frame"))


df_example %>% 
  pivot_longer(x1:x5) %>% 
  mutate(greater_120 = value > 120) %>% 
  group_by(year(date)) %>% 
  summarise(sum_120 = sum(greater_120,na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: no thats not what I´m looking. Maybe I mispelled in my post, rather than sum "count" would be more aapprobiate. Sorry for that!

So i wanna count how many observations for every station in every year are above 120.

Comment: @André_1090 - Actually, if we add `name` to the `group_by()` along with a `pivot_wider()` to this code, it can produce the output you requested. Rather than editing @Bruno's code, I posted a corrected version along with my answer. Also, based on the way `pivot_longer()` is specified, there's no need for the lubridate `year()` function in this solution. @Bruno feel free to edit your solution, and then I'll update my answer to reference yours.

Comment: @LenGreski nah it is fine