# How to interpret dplyr message `summarise()` regrouping output by 'x' (override with `.groups` argument)?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I started getting a new message (see post title) when running group_by and summarise() after updating to dplyr development version 0.8.99.9003.

Here is an example to recreate the output:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hablar)
df <- read_csv("year, week, rat_house_females, rat_house_males, mouse_wild_females, mouse_wild_males 
               2018,10,1,1,1,1
               2018,10,1,1,1,1
               2018,11,2,2,2,2
               2018,11,2,2,2,2
               2019,10,3,3,3,3
               2019,10,3,3,3,3
               2019,11,4,4,4,4
               2019,11,4,4,4,4") %>% 
  convert(chr(year,week)) %>% 
  mutate(total_rodents = rowSums(select_if(., is.numeric))) %>% 
  convert(num(year,week)) %>% 
  group_by(year,week) %>% summarise(average = mean(total_rodents))
```

The output tibble is correct, but this message appears:

> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'year' (override with `.groups` argument)

How should this be interpreted? Why does it report regrouping only by 'year' when I grouped by both year and week? Also, what does it mean to override and why would I want to do that?

I don't think the message indicates a problem because it appears throughout the dplyr vignette:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

I believe it is a new message because it has only appeared on very recent SO questions such as [How to melt pairwise.wilcox.test output using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62129863/how-to-use-pairwise-wilcox-test-using-dplyr) and [R Aggregate over multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973650/r-aggregate-over-multiple-columns/61974462#61974462) (neither of which addresses the regrouping/override message).

Thank you!

Answer (score 267, accepted):

It is just a friendly warning message about the resulting grouping structure; your output is correct.  By default, if there is any grouping *before* the `summarise`, it drops one group variable i.e. the last one specified in the `group_by`.  If there is only one grouping variable, there won't be any grouping attribute *after* the `summarise`. If there are more than one, the grouping is reduced by 1. So in your example since the input to summarise had two variables, the attribute for grouping is reduced to one, i.e. the resulting data frame would have 'year' as the grouping attribute.

As a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     group_by(am) %>% 
     summarise(mpg = sum(mpg))
#`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     am   mpg
#* <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0  326.
#2     1  317.
```

The message is that it is `ungroup`ing i.e when there is a single `group_by`, it drops that grouping after the `summarise`

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(am, vs) %>% 
   summarise(mpg = sum(mpg))
#`summarise()` regrouping output by 'am' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   am [2]
#     am    vs   mpg
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0  181.
#2     0     1  145.
#3     1     0  118.
#4     1     1  199.
```

Here, it drops the last grouping and regroup with the 'am'

If we check the `?summarise`, there is `.groups` argument which by default is `"drop_last"` and the other options are `"drop"`, `"keep"`, `"rowwise"`

> .groups - Grouping structure of the result.
>
> "drop_last": dropping the last level of grouping. This was the only supported option before version 1.0.0.
>
> "drop": All levels of grouping are dropped.
>
> "keep": Same grouping structure as .data.
>
> "rowwise": Each row is its own group.
>
> When .groups is not specified, you either get "drop_last" when all the results are size 1, or "keep" if the size varies. In addition, a message informs you of that choice, unless the option "dplyr.summarise.inform" is set to FALSE.

i.e. if we change the `.groups` in `summarise`, we don't get the message because the group attributes are removed

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(am) %>%
    summarise(mpg = sum(mpg), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     am   mpg
#* <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0  326.
#2     1  317.


mtcars %>%
   group_by(am, vs) %>%
   summarise(mpg = sum(mpg), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#     am    vs   mpg
#* <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0     0  181.
#2     0     1  145.
#3     1     0  118.
#4     1     1  199.


mtcars %>% 
   group_by(am, vs) %>% 
   summarise(mpg = sum(mpg), .groups = 'drop') %>%
   str
#tibble [4 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
# $ am : num [1:4] 0 0 1 1
# $ vs : num [1:4] 0 1 0 1
# $ mpg: num [1:4] 181 145 118 199
```

Previously, this warning was not issued and it could lead to situations where the OP does a `mutate` or something else assuming there is no grouping and results in unexpected output.  Now, the warning gives the user an indication that we should be careful that there is a grouping attribute

NOTE: The `.groups` right now is `experimental` in its lifecycle.  So, the behaviour could be modified in the future releases

Depending upon whether we need any further transformation of the data based on the same grouping variable (or not needed), we could select the different options in `.groups`.

Comment: What would be useful as well is to explain why this grouping attribute matters at all, because it is not obvious.

Comment: Does this mean that if you use .groups =  'drop' you don't have to use ungroup() before running certain other functions such as case_when or rowSums?

Comment: @SusieDerkins If you are using `summarise`, and with `groups = 'drop'`, then the group attributes are not there, so you don't need to `ungroup` (at least in the current scenario until this behaviior is changed in tidyverse)

Comment: Any advice on how to set the grouping behaviour globally so I don't have to enter it manually throughout my scripts to avoid the extra messages?

Comment: @MikeLawrence I tried checking the resources, but I  couldn't find it. thanks

Comment: @akrun Suggested this as a featuer, but was shot down (for understandable reasons I guess): https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5303#event-3412946530

Comment: Oh! to silence the message (keeping the old "drop_last" default), do options(dplyr.summarise.inform=F)

Comment: @MikeLawrence thanks! That's all I needed. It's a bit offputting that previously working code is suddenly throwing warnings (there should be no such thing as a _friendly_ warning).

Comment: I still find this new message to be confusing, even after making an effort to understand it.  "By default, if there is any grouping before the summarise, it drops one group variable i.e. the last one specified in the group_by."  What do you mean by "drop"?  I still see all grouping variables in the result.  It doesn't seem like anything was dropped.

Comment: @Arthur If it is by default, then it would drop the last group in the sequence `drop_last`.  Have you updated the output to the same object?

Comment: @Arthur grouping variables are a special attribute of data frames, they can change the behavior of mutate, for example if you compute a mean, it will compute the mean for each group instead of the mean over the whole data frame. It is generally better for `summarise` to drop the grouping by default `.groups = "drop"`. You can always use `group_by` again later if you need grouped computations.

Comment: I still don't understand what the purpose of .groups is.  If I group by year and week, then I would obviously want to summarize by year-week combinations.  When I run group_by and summarize using the different options for .groups I get exactly the same data frame.  Is .groups only relevant for ungrouping?

Comment: @BenW  It is just that when you have more than one groups, the default option removes the last in the order.  thus, there is still a group attribute i.e. year in your example.  Suppose you are doing some other operations on the entire column after summarise e.g. get the percentage etc with this group attribute, it may or may not be your desired.  This varies with the number of groups as well.  It is up to the programmer to determine whether they are okay with surprises or not

Answer (score 17):

Paraphrasing the accepted answer, it is just a friendly *confusing* warning.

> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'xxx'

should be read: the *output* is OK and contains **all grouping columns** as attributes, only the *grouping keys* may be limited.

Example of grouping `mtcars` by `cyl, am` calculating `mean(mpg)`

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg))
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [3]
    cyl    am avg_mpg
  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     4     0    22.9
2     4     1    28.1
3     6     0    19.1
4     6     1    20.6
5     8     0    15.0
6     8     1    15.4
```

The warning is saying that in the output only the first of the original grouping keys was preserved using the default `.groups = "drop_last"`. See the line `# Groups:   cyl [3]`.

Nevertheless, the attributes are complete, both `cyl` and `am` are defined.

Here a quick overview of the available option showing the result with the function `group_keys()`

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>% group_keys() 
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 3 x 1
    cyl
  <dbl>
1     4
2     6
3     8

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg), .groups = "keep") %>% group_keys() 
# A tibble: 6 x 2
    cyl    am
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4     0
2     4     1
3     6     0
4     6     1
5     8     0
6     8     1

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg), .groups = "drop") %>% group_keys() 
# A tibble: 1 x 0
```

The only visible consequence is while using a *cascading* summarization - the  example  below produce only one summary row as the group key were dropped.

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, am) %>% summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg), .groups = "drop") %>% summarise(min_avg_mpg = min(avg_mpg))
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  min_avg_mpg
        <dbl>
1   15.0
```

But as the *grouping attributes* are all available, it should be not a problem to *reset* the *group keys* as required using `group_by(cyl, am)` before the subsequent *summarization*.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is explained in ?summarise:
"When .groups is not specified, it is chosen based on the number of rows of the results:
If all the results have 1 row, you get "drop_last".
If the number of rows varies, you get "keep".".

Basically, you get such message when there is more than one option to be used as .groups= argument. The message warns you that one option has been used in the calculation of the statistics following the condition above: "drop_last" or "keep" for results with 1 or more rows, respectively.
Let's say that in your pipeline for some reason you applied two or more grouping criteria but you still need to summarise the data all across values regarless grouping, this can be done by setting .group = 'drop'. Unfortunately, this is only in theory, because, as you can see in @akrun's example, statistic values remain de same, no matter which option was set in .group = (I applied these different options to one of my datasets and obtained same results and same dataframe structure ('grouping structure is controlled by the .group= argument...'). However, by specifying the argument .group, no message is printed.

The bottom line is that when using summarise, if not grouping criteria is used, the output statistic is calculated across all rows and therefore 'results have 1 row'. When one or more grouping criteria are used, the output statistic is calculated within each group and therefore 'the number of rows varies' depending on the number of groups in data frame.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this use `summarise(avg_mpg = mean(mpg), .groups = "drop")`,
dplyr actually interprets the result table as grouped, thats why he shows you that warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in
https://r4ds.hadley.nz/data-transform.html#grouping-by-multiple-variables

> When you summarize a tibble grouped by more than one variable, each summary peels off the last group. **In hindsight, this wasn’t a great way to make this function work, but it’s difficult to change without breaking existing code.** To make it obvious what’s happening, dplyr displays a message

Answer (score 0):

This can be as a result of `summarise_all()` vs `summarise(across(everything()...` when you have 2 or more grouping columns

```
> tibble(gr1=c(1,1,2), gr2=c(1,1,2), val=1:3) %>% 
    group_by(gr1, gr2) %>% 
    summarise(across(everything(), mean))

#`summarise()` has grouped output by 'gr1'. 
# You can override using the #`.groups` argument.

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   gr1 [2]
    gr1   gr2   val
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   1.5
2     2     2   3


> tibble(gr1=c(1,1,2), gr2=c(1,1,2), val=1:3) %>% 
+     group_by(gr1, gr2) %>% 
+     summarise_all(mean)
# No warnings here

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   gr1 [2]
    gr1   gr2   val
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   1.5
2     2     2   3
```

So, the warning meaning: despite `everything()`, some of the columns will be skipped (grouping ones) in summarise()