# Why does summarize( ) behave differently in different machines?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
volume_info <- group_by(volume_info, Date)
volume_info <- summarize(volume_info, `Volume on Date` = sum(Volume))
```

The first line groups by  a column "Date", while the second line takes the sum of another column "Volume". On one account on my laptop and on my desktop, this works fine. However, on a different account on the same laptop (a "work" account), this throws a warning:

```
summarise() regrouping output by 'year' (override with .groups argument)
```

This then causes an error later on. In that machine, if I add the argument `.groups = "drop"`, the code works fine.

So I thought I'd just add `.groups = "drop"` everywhere. But then: in the machines where the original code works, what is happening is that a new column named ".group" is being added and it is filled with the value "drop"!

What is happening and how do I get the same behaviour across all machines -- especially, what's the "correct" behaviour if I want to collaborate? The code on my colleague's machines seem to work only when `.groups = "drop"` is not present.

Comment: Can you check the dplyr version in those different machines.  The `.groups`  lifecycle is experimental and it works in 1.0.0.  The correct approach would be to test it with the same versions or dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check your R and packages versions with running:

```
sessionInfo()
```

You probably have a different versions of software accross machines. Particularly in your case it seems to be a newer version of `dplyr` package, try that on your different machines:

```
packageVersion("dplyr")
#> [1] ‘1.0.0’
```

The message about regrouping output is only for your information to be clear what happens with your data frame during summarizing. It is not a warning nor error.

For more information about grouping see also:

- [How to interpret dplyr message `summarise()` regrouping output by 'x' (override with `.groups` argument)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override)
- [`dplyr::summarise()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)