# Ifelse statement within R's summarize function: dplyr

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I'm trying to count the number of visits a provider has conducted if the visit meets a qualification in R. In the commented out phrase, I can get each provider with the correct number of total visits, but when I try to set an if statement, I'm getting the provider repeated multiple times and not the correct visit count.

```
TeleHealth_Counts %>%
  group_by(TeleHealth_Counts$`Visit Provider`) %>%
  summarize(Video_Count = ifelse(`Type` ==  "Video Visit New", NA, sum(`Visit Count`, na.rm = TRUE)))
  #summarize(Tele_Count = sum(`Visit Count`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The other issue I'm facing is that when I assign this code to a variable so I can download the data, I'm getting an error: `summarise()` regrouping output by 'TeleHealth_Counts$`Visit Provider`' (override with `.groups` argument). How do I overcome this error or download the data frame I'm seeing in my console?

I've tried assigning it to a variable, to Tele_Count and to the data frame df_phys with the code below.

```
physicians <- unique(TeleHealth_Counts$`Visit Provider`)
df_phys <-data.frame(physicians)
```

Comment: The `.groups` thing is a warning, not an error. While it *can* be ignored (it is not breaking/stopping execution), it is safer to be explicit by adding `.groups=` to your summarise, like the warning suggested. See `?summarize` for details. As for repeated providers ... it could be anything. If you post sample data that reproduces that problem, we can help. (See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Type ==  "Video Visit New"` creates a vector of length same as number of rows in the group and `ifelse` returns the output same length as the condition we are checking, hence it repeats the rows.

Try the following :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- TeleHealth_Counts %>%
  group_by(`Visit Provider`) %>%
  summarize(Video_Count = if(any(`Type` ==  "Video Visit New")) NA_real_ 
                          else sum(`Visit Count`, na.rm = TRUE))
```

The message that you are receiving is a warning and not an error which is [safe to ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override) since it's a default behavior in `dplyr` 1.0.0 onwards unless you silence the warning. To create a csv file of the above dataframe you can use `write.csv` like :

```
write.csv(result, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: RonakShah, do you work `NA_real_` into your flow? While many (tidyverse) tools will be fine with the distinction, I've found other tools to be confused with a `lgl` column when something I did produced nothing summarizable, so `NA` is never case to `NA_real_`.

Comment: I usually use only `NA` (mostly because I don't remember to use `NA_real_/NA_integer_`) unless those `tidyverse` function "shout". But I think it is always better to be explicit.

Comment: Even if they don't complain, I think it may also be "declarative" in a sense, declaring what I think I should be getting out of this. Thus is the need for many of the `map_*` *typed* list-application functions in `purrr`, as well as `vapply` (base R). Thanks.