# Import multiple files and then output the calculation into one file

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have multiple .csv files with names "sub block#":

01 block1
01 block2
01 block3
02 block1
02 block2
02 block3

I would like to

1. get the mean for each participant grouped by "cue" (my current code tries get the mean for each file, but not for each subject)
2. save the output to one .csv file

```
files <- list.files(path="C:/Users/", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, 
    recursive=FALSE)
            for (file in files ){
              data<-read.csv(file)
              summarize.stat<-
                data%>% 
              group_by(Cue) %>%  # grouping stats
              drop_na() %>%
              summarize(count=n(),
                        mean.RT= mean(RT))
              write.csv(summarize.stat, paste("C:/Users/",'RTcue,csv',sep = ""), 
    row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
         }
```

This is what shows in the Console
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)

**
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `mean.RT`.
x error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'mean': object 'RT' not found**
i Input `mean.RT` is `mean(RT)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Cue = "Center".

So my questions are:
1.How to fix the error?
2.and how to get the mean by each subject?

Thank you for any advice! I've struggled with it for quite a while.

Comment: Do you `RT` column in the dataset?

Comment: yes! RT is in the dataset. I've checked the code works for one file

Comment: It may be possible that for atleast one or the files, the column names are not present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to tackle this issue. One option is to use a conditional logic with `if` to check whether the column `exists` in the read data and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
nm1 <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(files))
imap_dfr(setNames(files, nm1), ~ {
            dat <- read_csv(.x) 
            if(exists('RT', where = dat)) {
                   dat %>%
                     group_by(Cue) %>%
                     summarise(Count = n(), 
                        mean.RT= mean(RT, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')  %>%
             mutate(filename = .y)
            
      
               } else tibble(Cue = first(dat$Cue),
         mean.RT = NA_real_, filename = .y)
               }) %>%

    write_csv(path  =  file.path("C:/Users/", "RTcue.csv"))
```

---

Or another option is `tryCatch`

Comment: You are so right! One file doesn't. Now the code runs but didn't generate the output "RTcue.csv"

Comment: @Sophy Sorry, I will update it. One thing i noticed is that the file name is the same for all the output.  WOuldn't that overwrites the output?

Comment: In the Console it says "`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)". The output for each file is in the Console but losing the original file name. I would like the output to one .csv with the original file name. Thank you!

Comment: @Sophy Don't worry about that warning.  It is just a friendly warning.  You can use `.groups = 'drop'`.  Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override/62140681#62140681)

Comment: @Sophy I updated the post with the original file name with 'RTcue' as suffix.  Can you please check if that works

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing is it outputs to each individual file instead of one file with filename and mean.RT

Comment: @Sophy Ok, then I misunderstood from your code.  I thought you wanted multiple files.  WIll update

Comment: It won't generate the output file. this is the error "Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default"

Comment: @Sophy can you try with the update.  I couldn't test it.  So, it is just based on my intuition

Comment: @Sophy Sorry, an `,` was missing.  Can you test now