# Function takes an argument literally rather than the value of the argument

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I tried to create a function that would return me x largest MOLECULES based on how many unique PATIENT_ID each of them has, in descending order. That from a certain date until the last.

```
data <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID = c(1,1,2,2), dateM = c(ymd("2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-05-06","2019-12-15")), MOLECULES = c("mol1", "mol1", "mol1", "mol2"))


topx <- function(data, datefrom, var ,  x = 5){
  data %>%
  subset(dateM >= datefrom) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  summarize(pat = length(unique(PATIENT_ID))) %>%
  arrange(-pat) %>% 
  head(x) %>% 
  select(1)
}

topx(data = data, datefrom = "2016-04", var = MOLECULES, x = 2)
```

The wanted result in this case would be would be:

```
c("mol1","mol2")
```

However, it takes var as text and doesnt parse the MOLECULES in and tells me that.

```
 Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `var` is not found.
```

Comment: Heads up, there’s also the function [`slice_max`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html) in ‘dplyr’, which does something very similar; that said, I don’t think using it here would help. Apart from this, I recommend not mixing ‘dplyr’ functions with the base R equivalents. That is, use `filter` instead of `subset`. `filter` is more robust, provides better error messages when you do something wrong, and also works with interpolated variables via `{{…}}`. `subset` would *not* work with it. In principle the same is true with `head` vs `slice_head`, but the argument is less strong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cool function. There are special rules and operations when programming with `dplyr`. See more [here](https://dcl-prog.stanford.edu/tidy-eval-basics.html). Specifically, you need the `{{}}` operator.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

data <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID = c(1,1,2,2), dateM = c(ymd("2020-01-05","2020-01-06","2020-05-06","2019-12-15")), MOLECULES = c("mol1", "mol1", "mol1", "mol2"))

topx <- function(data, datefrom, var ,  x = 5){
  data %>%
    subset(dateM >= datefrom) %>%
    group_by({{var}}) %>%
    summarize(pat = length(unique(PATIENT_ID))) %>%
    arrange(-pat) %>% 
    head(x) %>% 
    select(1)
}

topx(data = data, datefrom = "2016-04-01", var = MOLECULES, x = 2) 
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   MOLECULES
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 mol1     
#> 2 mol2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Follow up question, when I use this function in its intended use, i.e. summarized based on if some values of MOLECULES are in top x, it throws me
`
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'dateM' (override with `.groups` argument)
`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
```, second message repeated for like 48 times. This persists even when I add `as.factor` or `as.character` to the end of the function

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a quasi quotation issue. `!!` does a one-to-one evaluation of an expression. For more information see https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html

Try:

```
topx <- function(data, datefrom, var ,  x = 5){
  var <- enquo(var)
  data %>%
  subset(dateM >= datefrom) %>%
  group_by(!!var) %>%
  summarize(pat = length(unique(PATIENT_ID))) %>%
  arrange(-pat) %>% 
  head(x) %>% 
  select(1)
}
```

Comment: That won’t work, you also need to `enquo` the variable — and `{{var}}` does both enquoting and unquoting/expanding for you.

Comment: Indeed this does not work, however, it is a useful but of information that I had no idea is a thing

Comment: oh sorry forgot to add the `enquo`!