# Use summarize and a for loop taking column names from a character vector

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataset which I cannot share here, but I need to create columns using a for loop and the column names should come from a character vector. Below I try to replicate what I am trying to achieve using the flights dataset from the nycflights13 package.

```
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)

flights <- nycflights13::flights
flights <- flights[c(10, 16, 17)]

var_interest <- c("distance", "hour")

for (i in 1:length(var_interest)) {
  flights %>% group_by(carrier) %>%
    summarize(paste(var_interest[i], "n", sep = "_") = sum(paste(var_interest[i])))
}
```

This code generates the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"  flights %>% group_by(carrier) %>%
    summarize(paste(var_interest[i], "n", sep = "_") ="
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

My actual dataset is more complex than this example and therefore, I need to follow this approach. So if you could help me find what I am missing here, that would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code can be modified to evaluate (`!!`) the column after converting the string to `sym`bol, while on the `lhs` of assignment (`:=`) do the evaluation (`!!`) of string as well

```
out <- vector('list', length(var_interest))
for (i in seq_along(var_interest)) {
out[[i]] <- flights %>%
   group_by(carrier) %>%
   summarize(!! paste(var_interest[i], "n", sep = "_") := 
       sum(!! rlang::sym(var_interest[i])), .groups = 'drop')
 }


lapply(out, head, 3)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  carrier distance_n
#  <chr>        <dbl>
#1 9E         9788152
#2 AA        43864584
#3 AS         1715028

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  carrier hour_n
#  <chr>    <dbl>
#1 9E      266419
#2 AA      413361
#3 AS        9013
```

---

There are multiple ways to pass a string column name and evaluate it.

1. As above stated, convert to a `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`).
2. Make use of `across` which can take either unquoted, or string or column index as integer i.e.  In that case, we don't even need any loop

---

```
flights %>%
      group_by(carrier) %>%
      summarise(across(all_of(var_interest), ~ 
               sum(., na.rm = TRUE), .names = '{.col}_n'), 
            .groups = 'drop') 
# A tibble: 16 x 3
#   carrier distance_n hour_n
#   <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 9E         9788152 266419
# 2 AA        43864584 413361
# 3 AS         1715028   9013
# 4 B6        58384137 747278
# 5 DL        59507317 636932
# 6 EV        30498951 718187
# 7 F9         1109700   9441
# 8 FL         2167344  43960
# 9 HA         1704186   3324
#10 MQ        15033955 358779
#11 OO           16026    550
#12 UA        89705524 754410
#13 US        11365778 252595
#14 VX        12902327  63876
#15 WN        12229203 151366
#16 YV          225395   9300
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to go through your codes carefully to understand fully. I need to familiarize myself with !!, sym and :=.

Comment: please excuse my lack of R knowledge... Why did you use sym in the second line of summarize but not in the first line? And what is .groups = 'drop' doing?

Comment: @TRa In the first line, i.e. on the lhs of `:=`, it is for assigning column name and string is enough, while on the `rhs`, we need to get the value of that column i.e. the reason I used `sym` + `!!`.  Regarding the `.groups`, I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override/62140681#62140681) may help you understanding more

Comment: thank you. I tried to use your code in my dataset but I got the following error:
`Error: Only strings can be converted to symbols
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: @TRa could be an issue with `packageVersion('dplyr')` I used `1.0.2`

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. Mine is `1.0.4`.

Comment: @TRa I updated my package `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.4’`.  It is running fine with the same code.  Maybe it is the `rlang` version.  I have `packageVersion('rlang')#
[1] ‘0.4.10’`

Answer (score 1):

A tidy way to do this might be to stack it longer rather than wider:

```
install.packages("nycflights13")
library(nycflights13)

flights <- nycflights13::flights %>%
  select(carrier,distance,hour)

by_carrier <- purrr::map_dfr( c('distance','hour'), function(x) {
  flights %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(carrier) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(n = sum(!!as.name(x))) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(key = x)
})
```

If you still want the `for` loop to append columns you can use the `!!as.name()` feature twice with something like

```
by_carrier <- NULL
for ( i in c('distance','hour')) {   
  df <- 
    flights %>%
    dplyr::group_by(carrier) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(!!as.name(i) := sum(!!as.name(i) ))
  by_carrier <- bind_cols(by_carrier,df)
}
```

although you'd have to clean up the `carrier` columns after that one.