# Counting Distinct Values By Two Groups and Summarise Error

Tags: r

I have a DF called Base that looks like this:

| Treatment | Gender | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | A |
| 1 | F | B |
| 1 | F | B |
| 1 | F | E |
| 2 | M | A |
| 2 | F | B |
| 2 | M | C |
| 2 | M | C |
| 2 | M | D |

And I would like to count by Treatment and Gender the number of *distinct* IDs, I have and get it in another dataframe, so I would have a DF called Uniques that would look like this:

| Treatment | Gender | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 1 |
| 1 | F | 2 |
| 2 | M | 3 |
| 2 | F | 1 |

I have tried to write this:

```
Uniques = Base %>% group_by(Treatment, Gender) %>% summarise(count = n_distinct(Base$ID))
```

But I get the following error:

```
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'Treatment' (override with `.groups` argument)
```

What is wrong and how could I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: It is not an error, but just a friendly warning.  You may check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override/62140681#62140681)

Comment: Also, there is an issue in `Base$`.  It shsould be just `n_distinct(ID))`.  `Base$` will select the entire column and thus gets the same value

Comment: your code works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much Akrun!