# How can I override using `.groups` argument to add the Date Variable to my Summary function?

Tags: r, statistics, grouping

I'm not sure how to pull the date from the data without the message:

" `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Id'. You can override using the `.groups` argument."

Below is the code I put in:

```
daily_activity_new<-daily_activity %>%
group_by(Id)%>%
summarise(Date_exersized=daily_activity$ActivityDate)
```

Comment: This doesn't actually summarize anything, the results are effectively the same as `select(daily_activity, Id, Date_exersized = ActivityDate)` (as a `grouped_df` class object). What aggregation are you really hoping to effect?

Comment: Can you show few lines of your input data and your expected output

Comment: (Especially with that much code, it is preferred to [edit] your question and put it there instead. Comments can easily be skipped by some readers, and when there are lots of comments, they can be hidden by the Stack interface. It's just best to keep the question itself as self-contained as possible. Thanks!)

Comment: Definitely, thanks for letting me know. I will edit the question now

Comment: do you just want to remove the message? This post explains that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override If there is something more that you want to do it would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need the data$ inside the `tidyverse`.  The `daily_activity$` extracts the full column from the data instead of the values for each group 'Id'.  It is not clear which function should be applied on the `ActivityDate`.  If we need to return the `min` or `first`, apply that.

```
library(dplyr)
daily_activity %>%
    group_by(Id)%>%
    summarise(Date_exersized= min(ActivityDate), .groups = 'drop')
```

Instead, if we want to create a new column, use `mutate` instead of `summarise`.  The warning message is a friendly one.  We can specify the `.groups` with one of the values i.e. `'drop'` removes the group attribute.  By default, it removes the last group