# recoding and collapasing multiple binary-coded columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns, dplyr

Struggling to find an elegant solution to this...

I have responses to "please select all that apply" questions, where each of choices A to F per question are coded as binary variables. So, for example, the first responder in the fake dataset below ticked only D for question 1, then A,C,D and E for question 2.

```
library(dplyr)

cols <- paste0('foo', '_', c(1:2, '3a', '3b')) %>%
  lapply(\(i) paste0(i, '_', LETTERS[1:6])) %>%
  unlist()

set.seed(1)
df <- lapply(cols, \(i) i = sample(0:1, 5, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  setNames(cols) %>%
  data.frame()

'data.frame':   5 obs. of  24 variables:
 $ foo_1_A : int  0 1 0 0 1
 $ foo_1_B : int  0 0 0 1 1
 $ foo_1_C : int  0 0 0 0 0
 $ foo_1_D : int  1 1 1 1 0
 $ foo_1_E : int  0 0 0 0 0
 $ foo_1_F : int  0 1 0 0 1
 $ foo_2_A : int  1 1 0 1 0
 $ foo_2_B : int  0 1 0 1 1
 $ foo_2_C : int  1 1 0 1 1
 $ foo_2_D : int  1 1 1 0 0
 $ foo_2_E : int  1 0 1 1 0
 $ foo_2_F : int  0 1 1 1 0
 $ foo_3a_A: int  0 1 1 1 1
 $ foo_3a_B: int  1 1 0 1 1
 $ foo_3a_C: int  1 1 0 0 0
 $ foo_3a_D: int  1 1 0 0 1
 $ foo_3a_E: int  1 1 0 0 0
 $ foo_3a_F: int  1 0 1 0 1
 $ foo_3b_A: int  0 0 1 1 0
 $ foo_3b_B: int  0 0 1 1 0
 $ foo_3b_C: int  1 1 1 0 0
 $ foo_3b_D: int  0 0 1 0 0
 $ foo_3b_E: int  0 0 0 1 1
 $ foo_3b_F: int  1 1 0 1 1
```

What I want is to recode `1` to each column's choice-letter (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, or `F`) and to concatenate the choices for each question so that I have something like this:

```
foo_1  D     ADF   D     BD    ABF
foo_2  ACDE  ABCDF DEF   ABCEF BC
foo_3a BCDEF ABCDE AF    AB    ABDF
foo_3b CF    CF    ABCD  ABEF  EF
```

This is as far as I got before realising I'd get stuck repeating similar code over and over:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(
  starts_with('foo') & ends_with('A'),
  ~ recode(., `1` = 'A', .default = NA_character_)
))
```

Comment: For the recoding step, I would use this: `df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(.x==1, str_extract(deparse(substitute(.x)), "[A-Z]$"), NA)))`. Not so sure how to go from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to reshape to long format with `pivot_longer` and then do a grouping by the sequence column generated earlier to `summarise` `across` the 'foo' columns by converting it to logical from binary, subset the 'grp' column and `paste`(`str_c`) them together

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "grp"), 
          names_pattern = "^(.*_.*)_(.*)") %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(across(-grp, ~ str_c(grp[as.logical(.)], 
          collapse="")), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  foo_1 foo_2 foo_3a foo_3b
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 D     ACDE  BCDEF  CF    
2 ADF   ABCDF ABCDE  CF    
3 D     DEF   AF     ABCD  
4 BD    ABCEF AB     ABEF  
5 ABF   BC    ABDF   EF
```

---

Or another option is

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~case_when(as.logical(.) ~ 
        rep(str_remove(cur_column(), ".*_.*_"), n())))) %>% 
   split.default(str_remove(names(.), "_[^_]+$")) %>%
   map_dfc(~ .x %>%
        unite(new, everything(), na.rm = TRUE, sep="") %>% 
        pull(new)) 
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  foo_1 foo_2 foo_3a foo_3b
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 D     ACDE  BCDEF  CF    
2 ADF   ABCDF ABCDE  CF    
3 D     DEF   AF     ABCD  
4 BD    ABCEF AB     ABEF  
5 ABF   BC    ABDF   EF
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
sapply(split.default(df, sub("(.*_.*)_.*", "\\1", names(df))), 
    function(x) apply(x, 1, FUN= function(y) paste(sub(".*_", "", 
     names(y))[as.logical(y)], collapse="")))
    foo_1 foo_2   foo_3a  foo_3b
[1,] "D"   "ACDE"  "BCDEF" "CF"  
[2,] "ADF" "ABCDF" "ABCDE" "CF"  
[3,] "D"   "DEF"   "AF"    "ABCD"
[4,] "BD"  "ABCEF" "AB"    "ABEF"
[5,] "ABF" "BC"    "ABDF"  "EF"
```

Comment: Thanks! The first of your 3 solutions makes sense to me. Except, the only thing I don't quite understand is the `.groups = 'drop'` part of `across`—what is this doing?

Comment: @jatx50  It is related to the `summarise` dropping groups attribute.  It is mentioned detailed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override/62140681#62140681)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `dplyr::rowwise` together with `dplyover::over` (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of {dplyover}). `dplyover::cut_names` allows us to select the string parts of the column names that we need. Then we can use this inside `across` to get those parts of `df` that we need to then get the `names` and subset them with the rowwise data `as.logical`. Finally we need to replace the names so that only the last letter remains.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

df %>% rowwise %>% 
  summarise(over(cut_names("_\\w$"), ~ 
    unlist(across(starts_with(.x))) %>% 
    {names(.)[as.logical(.)]} %>%  
    {paste(gsub(paste0(.x, "_"), "", .), collapse = "")}
  )) 

#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#>   foo_1 foo_2 foo_3a foo_3b
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1 D     ACDE  BCDEF  CF    
#> 2 ADF   ABCDF ABCDE  CF    
#> 3 D     DEF   AF     ABCD  
#> 4 BD    ABCEF AB     ABEF  
#> 5 ABF   BC    ABDF   EF
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this alternate solution. I already have `tidyverse` in my project so I've decided to use one of the above solutions.