# pivot_wider() update now requires name specification and need a new solution

Tags: r, tidyr

I am working with health data and have written code to group operation codes with their laterality code into code groups by the day on which they were performed.

I have written code which worked with `tidyr(1.1.4)` and now fails on `tidyr(1.2.0)`.

reprex below

```
    library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
~row, ~opdate_grp, ~side, ~OPERTN, ~OPDATE, ~opgrp,
1,1,"bilateral","W373","2018-03-23",1,
1,1,"bilateral","Z941","2018-03-23",1,
2,1,"bilateral","W374","2018-10-12",1,
2,1,"bilateral","Z941","2018-10-12",1,
3,1,"left","W383","2020-12-08",1,
3,1,"left","Z943","2020-12-08",1,
4,2,"none","O325","2013-03-31",2,
5,1,"none","G47","2012-01-22",1,
5,2,"none","C488","2012-01-25",2,
6,1,"none","X90","2018-12-25",1,
6,2,"none","T36","2018-12-28",2
        )
```

The next chunk was written to  reshape the data such that the resulting df included a single column for `OPERTN` & `OPDATE` and `opdate_grp` was an index indicating sequence of operations and dates so they could be filtered later on in the work flow.

The previous code (below) worked with `tidyr(version 1.2.0)`.

```
df %>% 
  # Make operation groups into a row for string searching
  pivot_wider(values_from= c(OPERTN, OPDATE), 
              names_sep = "",
              values_fill=NA,
              values_fn = list(OPERTN= ~unlist(.x)%>% toString(), 
                               OPDATE = ~.x[1]))
```

to produce a table where each row number has operation code groups which are indexed using `opgrp`:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 6
#    row opdate_grp side      OPERTN     OPDATE     opgrp
#  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>
#     1          1 bilateral W373, Z941 2018-03-23     1
#     2          1 bilateral W374, Z941 2018-10-12     1
#     3          1 left      W383, Z943 2020-12-08     1
#     4          2 none      O325       2013-03-31     1
#     5          1 none      G47        2012-01-22     1
#     5          2 none      C488       2012-01-25     2
#     6          1 none      X90        2018-12-25     1
#     6          2 none      T36        2018-12-28     2
```

However, when specifying `names_from = opdate_grp`, which is required in `tidyr(1.2.0)`, the resulting df contains seperate columns for each operation code gorup and date, which is annoying and stops my code from working. The reult is below:

```
df %>% 
  # Make operation groups into a row for string searching
  pivot_wider(values_from= c(OPERTN, OPDATE), 
              names_from= opgrp,
              names_sep = "_",
              #values_fill=NA,
              values_fn = list(OPERTN= ~unlist(.x)%>% toString(), 
                               OPDATE = ~.x[1])) 
# A tibble: 8 × 7
#    row opdate_grp side      OPERTN1    OPERTN2 OPDATE1    OPDATE2   
#  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     
#     1          1 bilateral W373, Z941 NA      2018-03-23 NA        
#     2          1 bilateral W374, Z941 NA      2018-10-12 NA        
#     3          1 left      W383, Z943 NA      2020-12-08 NA        
#     4          2 none      NA         O325    NA         2013-03-31
#     5          1 none      G47        NA      2012-01-22 NA        
#     5          2 none      NA         C488    NA         2012-01-25
#     6          1 none      X90        NA      2018-12-25 NA        
#     6          2 none      NA         T36     NA         2018-12-28
```

### What I have tried

I have tried repeating reshaping functions to bring the multiple columns into one but this is clunky and does not scale well.

I have tried rewriting `pivot_wider()` code but this fails as I cannot alter the invisible processes.

### Question:

Is there a work around to prevent this new behaviour or to fix this?

My real data contains up to **15 operation groups for each `row`** and over **10 million rows**, so the solution should scale and be stable (i hope) with future updates.

Comment: So what exactly is the desired output here? It would be nice to have that so we can verify our solution is correct.

Comment: If you want to create a single column for OPERTN and OPDAT, probably you don't need to use pivot_wider. Show your expected output to check

Comment: Given that your input data already has a single column for `OPERTN` and a single column for `OPDAT`, like @MrFlick I am struggling to see what your expected output might be.

Comment: I have added detail to make the desired output clear above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code works in `tidyr 1.2.0`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(OPERTN, OPDATE), 
    names_from = opgrp, values_fn = list(OPERTN= ~unlist(.x)%>% 
               toString(), 
                               OPDATE = ~.x[1]), names_sep = "")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 7
    row opdate_grp side      OPERTN1    OPERTN2 OPDATE1    OPDATE2   
  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <chr>     
1     1          1 bilateral W373, Z941 <NA>    2018-03-23 <NA>      
2     2          1 bilateral W374, Z941 <NA>    2018-10-12 <NA>      
3     3          1 left      W383, Z943 <NA>    2020-12-08 <NA>      
4     4          2 none      <NA>       O325    <NA>       2013-03-31
5     5          1 none      G47        <NA>    2012-01-22 <NA>      
6     5          2 none      <NA>       C488    <NA>       2012-01-25
7     6          1 none      X90        <NA>    2018-12-25 <NA>      
8     6          2 none      <NA>       T36     <NA>       2018-12-28
```

---

If the output required is a single column, use `group_by` with `summarise`

```
df %>%
   group_by(row, opdate_grp, side, OPDATE) %>% 
   summarise(OPERTN = toString(OPERTN), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 8 × 5
    row opdate_grp side      OPERTN     OPDATE    
  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>     
1     1          1 bilateral W373, Z941 2018-03-23
2     2          1 bilateral W374, Z941 2018-10-12
3     3          1 left      W383, Z943 2020-12-08
4     4          2 none      O325       2013-03-31
5     5          1 none      G47        2012-01-22
6     5          2 none      C488       2012-01-25
7     6          1 none      X90        2018-12-25
8     6          2 none      T36        2018-12-28
```

Comment: OP appears to want "a single column for OPERTN & OPDATE".

Comment: I thought the OP meant the expected output they got in 1.1.4 is not working with 1.2.0.  The OP's code results in error with 1.2.0 for me

Comment: @akrun, what is the function of the `.groups = "drop"` argument in summerise in this case?

Comment: @JisL By default, `summarise` drops the last grouping element in that order.  by using `.groups = 'drop', it drops the group attribute.  It is better not to have the grouping attribute in case you want to do some transformation on the whole data.  Also, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override/62140681#62140681)