# Multiply values in a data frame (based on a specific grouping) by a separate matrix using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to multiply values in a data frame (based on a specific grouping) by a separate matrix that puts some kind of weights on those values. The multiplication is part of a function that I wrote. I know how to do this in the most basic way. But I cannot understand how I can do it in a more realistic setting. I hope my example makes this problem clear.

I have the following example dataset:

```
set.seed(45)
tibble(site = rep(c(LETTERS[1:3]), each = 6),
       name = rep(c(letters[10:15]), 3),
       size = runif(18)) %>%
  arrange(site, name) -> d_tibble
```

I also have a matrix that could represent some kind of weights:

```
d_matrix <- matrix(0, 6, 6)
diag(d_matrix) <- 1
rownames(d_matrix) <- letters[10:15]
colnames(d_matrix) <- letters[10:15]

d_matrix
##   j k l m n o
## j 1 0 0 0 0 0
## k 0 1 0 0 0 0
## l 0 0 1 0 0 0
## m 0 0 0 1 0 0
## n 0 0 0 0 1 0
## o 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I also have a function that is supposed to multiply the vector `p` by the matrix `b`

```
test_fct <- function(a, b) {
  p <- a / sum(a)
  sum(p * (p %*% b))
}
```

Then I want to do something like this, i.e. using my function in `summarise()`:

```
#d_tibble %>%
#  group_by(site) %>%
#  summarise(y = test_fct(size, b))
```

But I don't know how to get `b`,i.e. the matrix, into my custom function so that its column names match the `name` variable when grouped by `site`.

One way I tried was to merge the matrix onto the data frame - that way I have everything in one data frame:

```
d_tibble %>%
  left_join(d_matrix %>%
              as_tibble() %>%
              mutate(name = colnames(d_matrix))) -> tibble_matrix_join
```

Than I have it all together but I need to somehow access the unique values of the `name` variable given the `site` grouping in order to select the correct columns (j, k, l, m, n, o) for the vector/matrix multiplication in my function `test_fct()`:

```
#tibble_matrix_join %>%
#  group_by(site) %>%
#  summarise(result = test_fct(size, b))
```

I tried to check if the general set-up works, that is for only one site and including all names in the matrix, and it does:

```
d_tibble %>% 
    filter(site == "A") %>% 
    pull(size) -> my_x 

test_fct(my_x, d_matrix)
## [1] 0.1858158

my_p <- my_x/sum(my_x)
sum(my_p * (my_p %*% d_matrix))
## [1] 0.1858158
```

Comment: @akrun it all works fine unless the number and values in the `name` variable  within the group vary, e.g. `d_tibble %>% slice_sample(n = 12) %>% arrange(site, name) %>% group_by(site) %>% summarise(out = test_fct(size, d_matrix))`. So I somehow have to select the correct `name` values, given the dataset and grouping to set up the correct matrix columns, or I get the error (see example above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example, all the columns in the d_matrix is found in the 'name' column of the tibble for all the 'site's.  If it is not the case, we may do

```
library(dplyr)
d_tibble %>%
   group_by(site) %>% 
   summarise(out = test_fct(size, d_matrix[intersect(row.names(d_matrix), 
         name), intersect(colnames(d_matrix), 
         name), drop = FALSE]), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  site    out
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A     0.186
2 B     0.264
3 C     0.218
```

-testing for a smaller data

```
d_tibble %>% 
  slice_sample(n = 12) %>%
  arrange(site, name) %>% 
  group_by(site) %>% 
   summarise(out = test_fct(size, d_matrix[intersect(row.names(d_matrix), 
         name), intersect(colnames(d_matrix), 
         name), drop = FALSE]), .groups = "drop")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  site    out
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A     0.227
2 B     0.416
3 C     0.481
```

Comment: This looks very good and works on the smaller sample! I will check against my actual dataset and get back to you soon. What does the `.groups = "drop"` do? Because when I leave it out it works too (on the smaller dataset). Also, the `drop = FALSE`, is this an argument of the the square brackets `[]`? It also works with it removed. THX!

Comment: @Stefan Regarding the edited comment, 1) `.groups` in `summarise` is described more in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140483/how-to-interpret-dplyr-message-summarise-regrouping-output-by-x-override/62140681#62140681), 2), `drop = FALSE` in `matrix/dataframe` when the subset returns only a single row/column, it drops the dimension attributes to become vector, `drop = FALSE`, maintains the dim attribute which may be essential for your `test_fct` function to work

Comment: Akrun, I hope you could help me answer one more question related to this question: How can I make sure that `d_matrix` as well as `df_tibble$name` are ordered in the same way before doing the vector/matrix multiplication? In my actual bigger dataset I get different results depending on whether I sort the matrix alphabetically first or not, such as: `d_matrix` vs `d_matrix[sort(rownames(d_matrix)), sort(colnames(d_matrix))]`. THX!

Comment: Actually I can replace `d_matrix[intersect(row.names(d_matrix), name), intersect(colnames(d_matrix), name), drop = FALSE])` , which is the second argument of the `test_fct()` with `d_matrix[name, name]`. This solved my problem I was describing above in my other comment.